# I printed {{comment.text}} in the text area. But there is a space in front. How do I remove blanks?

Tags: django, django-templates

I printed `{{comment.text}}` in the text area:

```
<tr>
    <td>code</td>
    <td colspan="3" id="my_code_{{comment.id}}">

        <textarea name="name" rows="10" cols="80">

            {{comment.text}}
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

But there is a space in front.
How do I remove blanks?

ex)
[output of django templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/manSa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have space between textarea. Change your code as shown below:

```
<textarea name="name" rows="10" cols="80">{{comment.text}}</textarea>
```

Remove that space infront of `{{comment.text}}`